# Laravel 8 site works well on localhost but not on shared hosting server

Tags: php, laravel

I have just completed my laravel 8 site. it works well on localhost, but generates errors on remote host. A look through the error log reveals the following error:

[28-Jul-2021 02:30:59 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/browz123/asherride.com/../asherride/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in /home/browz123/asherride.com/index.php on line 35

I have tried a couple of fixes, but none has worked. Below is a preview of my index.php

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../asherride/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
require __DIR__.'/../asherride/storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}
```

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

```
require __DIR__.'/../asherride/vendor/autoload.php';
```

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../asherride/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Did you run composer install on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your domain point to **public** directory instead of root directory.

Try to access your side with public slug eg. `http://example.com/public`. if its works it not pointed to public directory.

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that this resolves the given problem, where `vendor/autoload.php`could not be loaded